# Landscape OpenStack deployment

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack through Landscape but the Landscape UI says that

```
at least one machine must have multiple network connections.
```

I don't understand why my setup doesn't fullfill this requirement.

Here's the setup of one of my nodes:

[image]

As far as I can see, I have multiple network connections setup. `eno2` is directly connected to the internet, however, if I ssh into the node, only the 10.0.x.x interface is brought up.

What exactly do I need to do to fulfill the requirement? And why are "multiple network connections needed?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for the two-NIC node comes from MAAS... it is talking to the Internet on one NIC, and to the PXE-provisioned network on the other.

I do not know why your setup is failing detection however... someone will need to edit this answer with that bit :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/785872)

Comment: Please read again. He asked two questions, and I am answering the second.